# Table template for org-mode pdf export

Tags: pdf, emacs, export, org-mode, xelatex

I'd like my tables to be the same width (75% text width) in my org pdf export.

I've used http://emacs-fu.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/nice-looking-pdfs-with-org-mode-and.html to add a nice title page and some other customisations, but I can't work out how to stop the exporter putting \begin{center} around the tables.

Ideally I'd like to be able to control the export for these and potentially other entities, but having scoured the documentation I can't find much that will let me accomplish this at a global level rather than having to specify it on every table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick read through the org-mode code got this sorted.

```
(setq org-export-latex-tables-centered nil)
```

Loads of other variables listed in /lisp/org-latex.el for the curious.

Answer (score 2):

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :center nil
```

will do this for a single table, if you don't want to turn off centering globally.